# Unexpected token error while json parsing for string containing special characters

Tags: javascript, json, titanium

On trying to parse the following string on titanium Studio for mobile app project, I get the

error:
Unexpected token at profileSkills":"Analysis

```
des='[{"jobId":0,"jobPositionName":"NA","companyId":0,"companyDisplayName":"NA","profileSkills":"Analysis\r\nAnalysis\r\nQuality Assurance\r\nProject Management\r\nProgrammer Analyst\r\n"}]';
desjson=JSON.parse(des);
```

Can anyone help me , whether I can parse strings containing escape charaters using JSON.

If not, could you tell me the procedure to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the special characters with double-backslashes, because the JSON parser will expect them to be escaped.

```
var des='[{"jobId":0,"jobPositionName":"NA","companyId":0,"companyDisplayName":"NA","profileSkills":"Analysis\\r\\nAnalysis\\r\\nQuality Assurance\\r\\nProject Management\\r\\nProgrammer Analyst\\r\\n"}]';
```

If you are actually declaring the JSON **string** as a JavaScript string literal, then you have to account for the fact that when the JavaScript parser sees those escaped characters, it'll build a string with the **real** carriage return and line feed characters.  The JSON parser coming along after that won't like them.

If, on the other hand, your JSON is really coming from a server, then the JSON "on the wire" should *not* have doubled backslashes.

I should also note that there's rarely any reason to put a JSON string as a literal in JavaScript code. It might as well be a JavaScript object literal, in most cases. (I acknowledge that there might be some reason for it, of course.)

Comment: So I need to replace \r and \n with \\\r and \\\n respectively

Comment: @PriyankaKotari yes but see my update to the answer. It depends on where your JSON string is coming from.

Comment: Thank, its working with double backslash. Well, I am getting the json from a web service. So, I need to replace the \ with \\ in my javascript file

Answer (score 0):

You have two `\r\` in the string, that should be `\r\n`. Change those, and it validates as correct JSON.